# Do I have to close the JdbcTemplate connection and manually created Statements?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

For most of my queries I'm using the `query()` method of `JdbcTemplate` and a `RowMapper` which will do all the statement and connection stuff internally.

But in a specific case I need some additional metadata from the `ResultSet` and just want to handle the `Statement` and `ResultSet` by myself.

Do I have to close the `Statement` or `Connection` afterwards so that it will be returned to the connection pool or is this done by Spring even if I don't use the JdbcTemplate methods?

```
    Connection conn = getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

    /* ... */

    ps.close();    // should I do this?
    conn.close();  // and this?
```

Comment: If you are messing around with the connection yourself yes you have to close it. Or better use a `ConnectionCallback` or one of the other call back interfaces. Why would you need to manually get the connection? I haven't found the need (or urge) to do so when using `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: To easily generate some reports I just want to dump the whole query result in an object which consists of a header array with the column names and a two dimensional array of rows / columns for the values. I want to use the same method for different statements so I have to get the header names from the ResultSet.

Comment: That is exactly what a `ResultSetExtractor` is meant to help you with.

Comment: if you manually handle connection, resultset etc, you shouldn't be using jdbctemplate int he first place. The point of the template is to handle those for you. However - you shouldn't ditch the template, but use the methods it provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to close it by yourself.
Look [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/0da8dee289e4cbe353d4bd6cc0935cd62ab27901/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L605), the template implementation is doing it when you execute it with the template

Comment: I think I'll use the `DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection()` method as well :)